# Negative Values of Area when calculating area Under a Curve

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have obtained coefficients of a polynomial using polyval in python. I used the following code to calculate area of the polynomial. The curve appeared above y=0 line when visualised. But the area when calculated appeared to be negative. Could you please someone help me what is the issue with the following code.

```
import numpy as np
# insert the coefficents of the polynomial
p = np.array([ 2.60349395e+09, -3.34913329e+10,  1.87588633e+11, -5.85791667e+11,
           1.04784500e+12, -8.03652884e+11, -8.37573977e+11,  3.17205629e+12,
           -4.33851893e+12,  3.48269443e+12, -1.71966834e+12,  4.86703099e+11,
           -6.07938187e+10])

def f(x):
    return ((p[0]*(x**12))+(p[1]*(x**11))+(p[2]*(x**10)))+(p[3]*(x**9))+(p[4]*(x**8))+
            (p[5]*(x**7))+(p[6]*(x**6))+(p[7]*(x**5))+(p[8]*(x**4))+(p[9]*(x**3))+
            (p[10]*(x**2))+(p[11]*(x**1))+(p[12]))

N = 1000
#insert the initial value of independent variable
x1=1
#insert the final value of the independent variable
x2 = 1.578687

dx = (x2 - x1)/N

A = 0
t=x1

while t<=x2:
  dA=f(t)*dx
  A = A +dA
  t = t + dx

# Area under the curve
print("A=",A)
```

Comment: cant you use `scipy.integrate`?

Comment: Thanks. I am trying that one now. But still do not make sense why the above show ne negative area value.

Answer (score 0):

The area is negative because the function `f(t)` is strictly negative in that interval. You can see that by quickly plotting the function making use of `np.arange` and the `matplotlib` package.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# insert the coefficents of the polynomial
p = np.array([ 2.60349395e+09, -3.34913329e+10,  1.87588633e+11, -5.85791667e+11,
          1.04784500e+12, -8.03652884e+11, -8.37573977e+11,  3.17205629e+12,
          -4.33851893e+12,  3.48269443e+12, -1.71966834e+12,  4.86703099e+11,
          -6.07938187e+10])

def f(x):
   return (p[0]*(x**12) + p[1]*(x**11) + p[2]*(x**10)+ p[3]*(x**9) + p[4]*(x**8) +
           p[5]*(x**7) + p[6]*(x**6) + p[7]*(x**5) + p[8]*(x**4) + p[9]*(x**3) +
           p[10]*(x**2) + p[11]*x+p[12])

plt.plot(np.arange(0, 2, 0.001), f(np.arange(0, 2,  0.001))) # plotting
```

[image]

You can also use exceptions to check for negative values of `f(t)` when integrating:

```py
N = 1000
#insert the initial value of independent variable
x1 = 1
#insert the final value of the independent variable
x2 = 1.578687

dx = (x2 - x1)/N

A = 0
t = x1

while t<=x2:
    if f(t) < 0:
        # raise exception if negative value is encountered, integration will stop.
        raise Exception("Negative values encountered") 
    else:
        dA = f(t)*dx
        A = A +dA
        t = t + dx
        


# Area under the curve
print("A=",A)
```

Output:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-2aea71dc1318> in <module>
     12 while t<=x2:
     13     if f(t) < 0:
---> 14         raise Exception("Negative values encountered")
     15     else:
     16         dA = f(t)*dx

Exception: Negative values encountered
```

Comment: Thank you Jay for the comment. I think that's the issue...

Comment: @GayanAravinda I'm glad I was of help, if you think this answer is correct, as per community guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers you can consider marking it as correct.